# I execute command in android apk, but I can't get right returns

Tags: java, android, linux, shell, system

I execute system command in android app, but I can't get right execute results.

Here is my code:

```
String cmd = "ls /";

try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

    p.waitFor();

    if (p.exitValue() != 0) {
        System.out.println(p.exitValue());
        Log.d("test",p.exitValue()+" ");
    }

    String s;
    List<String> stdout_list = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.d("test", s);
        s = s + "\n";
        stdout_list.add((String)s);
    }

    callableGetData.stdout_list = stdout_list;
} catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
}
```

cmd, such as `ls`, will get the wrong answer `1`, but if I use `ps -A`, I will get right answers. The wrong answer `1`, may be the `exitValue()`.

What causes this?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663604/how-to-use-runtime-getruntime-execcmd helps? If you want to pass arguments to a command, pass them as a String array, not all in one String.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) for example. It says:

> Exit status:
>
> ...
>
> 1 if minor problems (e.g., cannot access subdirectory)

Your app probably does not have sufficient privileges to `ls` the whole root directory `/`.

Comment: it's probably my app is not a signed apk?

Comment: IIRC, every app must be signed, else it cannot be installed. I suggest you try to `ls` one of the app's [private directories](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()).